# Is there a way to add or update file in tar.gz(tgz) without decompress?

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

I'm looking for a way to update tgz file.
I know what I can update tgz file by unzipping it, inserting file in directory and re-compressing it.
But I do not want decompressed file was created in my disc.

Tar has 'r' option(--append) what appending files to the end of an archive but when I use tar with 'r' option, console logged 'cannot update compressed archive.', 'Error is not recoverable: exiting now.'

If it is impossible, I cannot help but if there is a way, plz let me know.

I modified my question according to Basile Starynkevitch's comment.

This is command for testing.

```
tar -rf myComppressedFile.tgz insert.txt
```

Result

```
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

vim myCompressedFile.tgz

```
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./file3.txt
./directory1/
./directory1/file4.txt
```

what I want to update

```
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./file3.txt
./directory1/
./directory1/file4.txt
./insert.txt <<<< I want to add like this file
```

My tgz file is about more 100 megabytes.

Comment: Why do you ask ? What is the use case ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62947633/edit) your question by providing some [mre] and some motivation for your question. What is your `.tgz` file? How big is it (gigabytes, terabytes....)

Comment: Sounds like you should use the zip format instead, which supports what you want to do.

Comment: Do you have terabytes of data? What will happen to you if some files are lost or have a corrupted archive ?

Comment: See this question for somewhat more information: [U&L: How to add/update a file to an existing tar.gz archive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13093)

Comment: What kind of software (for what industry) are you working? What happens to you if some data gets lost or corrupted?

Comment: What forbids you to use other approaches (e.g. [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)?) since your data is tiny?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to add or update file in tar.gz(tgz) without decompress?

## No, there is no way.

Since compression by `gzip` happens on the entire `tar` archive (after making the `tar` ball). Observe the runtime behavior of your `tar` command using [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (so read [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html)

#### Read documentation of [tar(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html). Study the source code of [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) (it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)).

On my Debian/Sid/x86-64, the `libc6-dev` package provides the `/usr/include/tar.h` header. I invite you to look inside that header file, it describes the format of `tar` balls.

**Consider using *other* approaches:** some [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database, using [postgresql](https://postgresql.org/) or [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/) or [GDBM](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/), some [afio](https://linux.die.net/man/1/afio) archive (where each file is perhaps compressed before archiving it). See also the [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/) utility.

> I'm looking for a way to update tgz file

### Why ?

Did you consider instead using [*version control*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) on the underlying files *before* their archival with `tar`? Something like [git](https://git-scm.com/)?

> But I do not want decompressed file was created in my disk.

### Why ?

The decompressed file might be a temporary one....

Of course, you would need to have different approaches if you deal with a few megabytes of data or if you have a few petabytes of data. Of course, if you are developing a critical embedded application (e.g. medical devices, interplanetary satellite software, [DO-178C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C) software systems), things could be different.

**There are lots of trade-offs to consider** (including money and development time and economical impact of loss of data or of corrupted archive and legal regulations regarding the archive and its data integrity : in a [flight recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_recorder) you should ensure the data is readable after the crash of an aircraft).

> My tgz file is about more 100 megabytes.

**This is tiny**, and practically would fit (for most Linux systems in 2020, even a cheap [RaspBerryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)) in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). You might use some file system kept in RAM (e.g. `tmpfs`)

Comment: I let Jenkins generate key files and insert it in my tgz file before tranfer my tgz file by ftp. I want to generate different key files every time Jenkins build project. Why do I ask this question, I thought it is unnecessary to decompress tgz file for inserting little bit file.

Comment: Don't comment an answer, please *edit* your own question to improve it. Explain us if you deal with petabytes or just megabytes of data

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved my problem by decompressing, changing the file and then compressing it again. As I am not yet an experienced developer, it seems difficult to solve my problem right now according to your answers as I wish. After solving all the other tasks, I will try to find a way to solve the problem using your answers. Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware that we did not understood what your actual problem is. In particular, do you use Linux just for some random website (e-shop), or do you use Linux inside some critical embedded hardware (e.g. a Covid respirator)?